# How to get the Three.js import/export scripts into Blender on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, script, path, blender

I have been working with 3D primitives in Three.js, but now I want to import some models. I plan on using Blender, which I have just downloaded with:

`sudo apt-get install blender`

However, I was instructed to put the import/export scripts in the `.blender/2.62/scripts/addons` folder, but it does not exist! `.blender/2.62` does exist, but it only has a `config` folder.

The next thing I did is manually changed the script search path in Blender's preferences from  `//` to my `homefolder/scripts`, which contained the required `io_mesh_threejs` folder (which, in turn had the `.py` scripts inside).

I saved the changes, restarted Blender, but still nothing: in the menu there is no mention of Three.js at all!

What do I do? It would be great if I knew the installation path for Blender, because maybe I could put those scripts there manually. Where should it be installed?

**EDIT:** these are the scripts I'm talking about, along with the instructions: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/blender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scripts should go in `/usr/lib/blender/scripts/addons/`.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to give the scripts execute rights. Enter this in the folder of the addons:

```
chmod -R +x /usr/lib/blender/scripts/addons/io_mesh_threejs
```

There may be errors otherwise.